# keyboard disappears while orientation change to landscape mode

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I am enabling orientation change in `focusChangeListener` of an `edittext` in my app.

It is working fine, but the issue is if the user flips the keyboard to landscape mode keyboard disappears.

It will come up only if user tap on `edittext` again or change orientation to portrait mode.

I need to display keyboard in landscape mode without touching the `edittext`.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, its a bad idea to mess with the default IME behavior because there are devices out there with hardware keyboards.

Now, that you have been warned, listen for the orientation change and if the keyboard was visible before the change and there is no hardware keyboard on the device, show the keyboard manually.

Answer (score 0):

Try using  `android:configChanges="orientation"` into your manifest class.

```
  <activity
        android:name=".classname"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"

         >
```

if works then accept it.