# Android Development: Soft Keyboard Problems After Orientation Changes

Tags: android, keyboard, orientation, show

I have a fragment that consists of a ListView. Each cell of this ListView contains an EditView.

Let's pretend that while I'm typing text, I decide to rotate my device. Problems are introduced:

1) The keyboard closes. I would like to keep the keyboard visible after rotating the device.
2) Much worse, any listeners attached to each EditText object is no longer active. Although the keyboard may begin to appear, the text inside that focused EditText is not modified as I'm typing.

How should I deal with these issues?

Source code:
Fragment...

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);

    mListView = (ListView)mView.findViewById(R.id.listView);

    prepareListData();

    mAdapter = new ThermostatExtrasListAdapter(mContext, mThermostat, listItems);

    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    prepareListViewListeners();

    return mView;
}

private void prepareListData() {
    listItems = new ArrayList<Object>();

    for (Object nextObject : mObjects) {
            listItems.add(nextObject);
    }
}
```

Adapter...

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    DataStructure obj = (DataStructure)this.getItem(position);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_textfield, parent, false);

    if(convertView != null) {
        final EditText valueObject = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textEdit);
        valueObject.setText(obj.value);
        valueObject.setTag(obj);

        valueObject.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                extraObject.value = s.toString();
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }
        });

        valueObject.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                    //TODO: Do something...
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: can you post your code.?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12003584/keyboard-disappears-while-orientation-change-to-landscape-mode

Comment: done: posted the source code relevant to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Add this line in your manifest :
 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged"
2)You should not create a listener for each EditText.
This code should work :

```
private OnEditorActionListener mOnEditorActionListener = ...;
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ...
        valueObject.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                extraObject.value = s.toString();
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }
        });

        valueObject.setOnEditorActionListener(mOnEditorActionListener);
        ...

}
```